# What do all the common maps "preserve"?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, category-theory, morphism

I am trying to organize all the different "morphisms" in my head. To help me remember, I am trying to imagine what these maps "preserve." By "preserve" I mean an invariant under the mapping. Can you help me fill in the gaps?

An isometry of a manifold preserves lengths and angles.

An isometry of a vector space preserves the inner product.

A homeomorphism of a manifold preserves topological properties (how do we quantify this?)

A diffeomorphism of a manifold preserves "smoothness" as well as topological properties.

An injection between any two sets preserves "uniqueness"

A surjection between any two sets preserves the "wholeness" of a set

An isomorphism between vector spaces preserves operations: scalar multiplication and vector addition.

A morphism preserves...?

Is this a good way of categorizing these maps? Should I be remembering them differently?

Comment: The only "blanks" you seem to have is "how do we quantify presevation of topological properties" (for homeomorphism) and "what's preserved by a morphism?"  Unfortunately, the latter is not a question with a unifying general answer, at least if you mean a "morphism" in the sense of category theory.  In fact, since catgeories are not necessarily concrete, morphisms don't need to be "maps" at all.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "A surjection preserves 'wholeness'" is actually supposed to mean.

Comment: Also, a few refinements: an isometry between vector spaces is an example of an isometry between manifolds; it turns out that in the case of vector spaces, preserving lengths and angles is equivalent to linearity and preserving inner products.  It is also notable that isomomorphisms, in addition to preserving operations, are also both injective and surjective.  The more general class of maps that preserve operations is that of homomorphisms.

Comment: This like asking what does "a word means". Which word, and in what context? A morphism is just a general name for a very general type of mathematical object, and without proper context it's nearly impossible to say that it preserves one thing or another.

Comment: I disagree with the claim about "isometry" on vector spaces.  Vector spaces per se have no notion of length or angle.  The more apt context for this would be inner product spaces.  There are other misconceptions embedded here and there in the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Though your examples might require some refinements (as written some in the comments), you basically got the idea: there is something common in whatever kind of 'morphisms'.

And the most general thing in common, is that idenitites will always be included and they all are closed under composition, which makes their class a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory).

Most of your lines specifically take the *invertable* ones of the given type of morphisms. (E.g. homeomorphisms are the invertible morphisms in the category 
$\quad$ [objects: *topological spaces*, morphisms: *continuous functions*].)